# Can a HTTPS request expire?

Tags: https

Are there any measures in HTTPS that ensures requests from a client are fairly new?
Mostly I'm interested in what can be configured serverside. I've found information about TTL, but this is only client based. How does a server make sure that messages are new?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: A server can use 'session' to know whether it's a new request, or if it's a user that browses the site.

Comment: Have you ever tried accessing web resources or APIs when your computer time is wrong? It often won't work because of the difference, although that would require *quite* an old request (it also depends very much on what is being accessed)

Comment: They really can't "not be new" The requests come in and the server can accept or reject (drop) them, but there's no facility built into HTTP/S for storing them up for a later processing. What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: OP here. If you look at WSS, you have the ability to add a timestamp to your message. If the message is too old, it's rejected. Does HTTPS have something built in that is comparable to this?